# jQuery after submit, "data" is not displayed as HTML

Tags: jquery, forms, submit, shadowbox

I am using this code bellow to submit a form which is "lighthouse" or "Shadowbox". Any ways a window pops up and the rest of the screen gets dark.

```
    var frm = $('#contactForm1');
    frm.submit(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
        url: frm.attr('action'),
        data: frm.serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });

    return false;
    });
```

which I took it :[From here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657898/does-a-working-jquery-shadowbox-form-example-exist). I am submitting the form to submit.php script. It works fine when submitting but it return the result from submit.php as "alert" and it is not HTML, it is all pure text that I see them are HTML.

My question is how can I submit the form so the result is back in that shadowbox and not as alert?

Comment: That's because it's being alerted and you can't use html in an `alert()`. Try using: `$("#sb-wrapper-inner").html(data)`.

Answer (score 1):

use can also use [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) is a tool for displaying images, html content and multi-media in a Mac-style "lightbox" that floats overtop of web page.

Comment: sorry I don't want to use so many scripts from different sources for future development reasons. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As @Joe said, you can't use html in alert(), so If you want to display Html that way, better use [Dialog | jQuery UI][1]

**EDIT**: since you're using `bootstrap` you can do it like that:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
 var frm = $('#contactForm1');
 frm.submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function (data){
              $("#modal-body").html("Your result:" + data);
           }
       });
    });
});
```

Here a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ouadie/bREQq/

Just use the code on `jsfiddle.net`, and put this in `<head>`

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>   

 <!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: what is the #dialog ?. Do I have to create another div? and where? in the main page or in the popup (lightbox window)?
I want this to replace the current #contactForm1 contents which is the original form. How would I do that?

Comment: yes you have to add a `<div id="dialog" />` on the same page, check http://jqueryui.com/dialog/ for more examples

Comment: jQuery web site sucks. They never explain things. I hate it when they say for example .submit() is for such and such and you never know what the hell is .submit() where are the other parts.

Comment: I just added a simple example of using `dialog()`

Comment: thansk. I tried your code but when I click on submit, I replaces the main page where the form  is submitted.

Comment: this web site is like Microsoft Access to be learned. When you said I have added, for few minuets I was look to see where is the added example.

Comment: put your javascript inside `$(document).ready(function() {
  // your scripts here
});`

Comment: $(document).ready(function() { // your scripts here }); did not help. still the same.

Comment: put all your scripts in the `<head>` part, if you check the console you'll see an error `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Comment: add `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css` and `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` so you can use `dialog`

Comment: put `jquery.js` the first and also `bootstrap`

Comment: I added all googleapi codes (corrected the css url to: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css) and still the same. It submits to the enw page> check it out: http://abstutor.com/tests/form00/

Comment: there are two `<script>` at the bottom of the page, try to put them before other scripts

Comment: I just did and the same [here](http://abstutor.com/tests/form00/). How ever if I put all scripts at the <head> the contents disappear from the screen [in Header here](http://abstutor.com/tests/form00/inheader.html)

Comment: ok, change `<div id="dialog" />` by `<div id="dialog"> </div>`

Comment: ok, changed it to <div id="dialog"> </div> and the same problem.

Comment: can you suggest completely new. I need a link in page where visitor clicks and gets the dialog window with form. Then after submit, the result is shown in the same form (dialog) and visitor can close it.
it should be based on jQuery and/or bootstrap.

Comment: hi, thanks for the efforts but the same problem. [link](http://abstutor.com/tests/form00/)

Comment: you forgot to remove `$("#dialog").dialog({ autoOpen: false });` you should use the entire script that I updated in my solution

Comment: Here is a working solution http://jsfiddle.net/ouadie/bREQq/ sorry I forgot to save it the last time.

Comment: same problem. did not help. check it out.

Comment: where is the last link that implements the last solution ?

Comment: I have one link from the beginning and keep updating it [here] (http://abstutor.com/tests/form00/)

Comment: the only change I saw in jsfiddle is the javeascript with the word " $(".modal-body").html("Your result:" + data);" but I changed the whole javasccript. I am using this link http://jsfiddle.net/ouadie/bREQq/

Comment: yes, but in jsfiddle I didn't use `$(document).ready(function() {` like I did in my solution, just add it.

Comment: Wow! Worked. Perfect in all 3 browser I tested it! Thank you very much Ouadie.